# Does dkms do this?

Tags: linux

I installed bbswitch and patched the source for dkms at **/var/lib/dkms/bbswitch/0.8/source/bbswitch.c**

I did not touch **/usr/src/bbswitch-8.0/bbswitch.c**

But now I see that **/usr/src/bbswitch-8.0/bbswitch.c** is patched since the patch file was in there and that **/usr/src/bbswitch-8.0/bbswitch.c** has been modified...

Did dkms automatically patch **/usr/src/bbswitch-8.0/bbswitch.c** ?

Answer (score 0):

Ah...I am realizing now that **/var/lib/dkms/bbswitch/0.8/source/** is symlinked to **/usr/src/bbswitch-8.0**